# Deleting a particular view in a list of views

Tags: java, android

I am new to android.I am trying to add and remove views as in contacts application in android emulator. I am using layout inflator to continuously adding views .When I am deleting one of the view it gets deleted from backwards.
The actual problem is I cannot find out the id for the exact button I'm clicking.

```
  public void plusButton(View v)
    {

    layout++;
    v=(View)findViewById(R.layout.newlayout);
    v = linflator.inflate(R.layout.newlayout, null); 
    rl1.addView(v);
    v.setId(layout); 

    if(layout==1)
    {
        Button office=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonType);
        System.out.println("button id found");
            office.setText("item 1");


    }
    else if(layout==2)
    {
        Button office=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonType);
        office.setText("item 2");

    }
    else if(layout==3)
    {
        Button office=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonType);
        office.setText("item 3");
    }
    else 
    {
        Button office=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonType);
        office.setText("item goes");
    }

 }

public void minusButton(View v)
{                                     
    v = (View)findViewById(layout);
    rl1.removeView(v);
    layout--;
}
```

Also the button text of first button only changes

help me..

Comment: in your posted code,In second line you are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `button.settag()` and `button.gettag()`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use getParent() to get the parent in the view group and remove that view